# Is there any way to set client request execution id?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, graphql

I am working on a Spring Boot project that utilizes GraphQL for querying data. I'm currently facing an issue where I cannot set the execution ID on my GraphQL client requests.

I have set up my project with Spring Boot and integrated the GraphQL support using the graphql-spring-boot-starter dependency. I have successfully defined my GraphQL schema, resolvers, and queries, and I am able to perform basic GraphQL queries without any problems.

However, I now need to set a custom execution ID on my GraphQL client requests for better traceability and monitoring purposes. The default execution id is always set to "1" for every request. I have checked the DefaultClientGraphQlRequest.class and there is no id field, so I don't know how to proceed right now.

My graphql client:

```java
    @Bean
    WebSocketGraphQlClient webSocketGraphQlClient(@Value("${" + GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT_URL_PROPERTY + "}") String graphqlUrl) {
        var client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
        return WebSocketGraphQlClient.builder(graphqlUrl, client)
                                     .build();
    }
```